# protobuf with inheritance?

Tags: protocol-buffers

Is it possible to use [protobuf](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) with classes who inherit?

I want to do something like this

```
class Expr;
class AddExpr : Expr;
class CallFunc: Expr;

class FunctionBody{
    repeatable Expr expr;
}
```

Comment: A good discussion can be found in this blog post:  http://www.indelible.org/ink/protobuf-polymorphism/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not in the core implementation - you would want to use encapsulation instead.

However if you are using *just* [protobuf-net](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/), as code-first, I hack around it:

```
[ProtoInclude(1, typeof(AddExpr))]
[ProtoInclude(2, typeof(CallFunc))]
[ProtoContract]
class Expr {}

[ProtoContract]
class AddExpr : Expr {} 
[ProtoContract]
class CallFunc: Expr {}

[ProtoContract]
class FunctionBody{
    private List<Expr> expressions;
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public List<Expr> Expressions {
        get { return expressions ?? (expressions = new List<Expr>()); }
    }
}
```

Of course, I'm assuming there is some additional detail in the classes - "as is" you could just use an enum (which *is* well-supported).