# Protobuf-net not serializing generic type inherits from generic type

Tags: c#, generics, protobuf-net

I've this model:

```
[ProtoContract]
[ProtoInclude(2, typeof(TestRequest<>))]
public class XClass<T>
{
    public XClass()
    {
    }

    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public T Value { get; set; }
}

[ProtoContract]
public class TestRequest<T>: XClass<T> where T : ConcreteClass
{

    public TestRequest()
    {
    }

}

[ProtoContract]
public class ConcreteClass
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And if I try to serialize and deserialize with protobuf-net :

```
TestRequest<ConcreteClass> request = new TestRequest<ConcreteClass>();
request.Value = new ConcreteClass() { Name = "test" };
MemoryStream msTestString = new MemoryStream();
Serializer.Serialize(msTestString, request);
msTestString.Position = 0;
request = Serializer.Deserialize < TestRequest<ConcreteClass>>(msTestString);
```

And after this, If I inspect request.Value , it's null.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What's the value of msTestString before you try to deserialize it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [protobuf with inheritance?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4746678/protobuf-with-inheritance)

Comment: No duplicate.  I've only problem if is generic type that inherits from another generic type.

Comment: Have you ever got around this issue? I have just recently ran into this exact problem with generic to generic inheritance.

Comment: @xvpower I'll add a clearer answer...

Answer (score 1):

This is by design with protobuf-net. One of the reasons it is so quick and light on data is that it doesn't worry about type information. This, unfortunately (Well, depending on your point of view) completely rules out inheritance with it.

see [protobuf with inheritance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4746678/protobuf-with-inheritance) for more info

Answer (score 1):

From protobuf-net's perspective, it is *primed and ready* to receive the open generic type `TestRequest<>` as field 2... however, nothing ever exists as `TestRequest<>`: only closed generic types exist as actual objects, so `TestRequest<>` is simply not useful to protobuf-net.

What *would* work in some scenarios is:

```
[ProtoContract]
[ProtoInclude(2, typeof(TestRequest<Foo>))]
[ProtoInclude(3, typeof(TestRequest<Bar>))]
[ProtoInclude(4, typeof(TestRequest<Blap>))]
```

However, it probably isn't a good idea to mix this with generics themselves.

I suspect what you *actually* want is:

```
[ProtoContract]
[ProtoInclude(2, typeof(TestRequest<T>))]
public class XClass<T> {}
```

however, I have no idea if that even compiles, let alone if it is what you are after. In reality, my opinion is that if you're getting tied into this kind of knot, you're *probably* over-complicating your serialization model - often the result of trying to serialize you primary domain model - and maybe it is time to move to a simpler, dedicated model.